# AngularJS $http.get not retrieving the backend data

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

i am new to the "Angularjs and Nodejs" combination and i am trying to make a simple crud app. The problem is, when i use $http.get in angular, it doesnt go to the backend.

Here are my codes:

server.js (nodejs)

```
var connection = util.getDBConnection();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//routes = require('./routes/routes')(app, connection);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
console.log("Backend");
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM user_info;", function(err, rows){
            if(err){
                res.redirect('/error');
                console.log("Error in the database: " + err);
            } 
            res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
            console.log("Connected to the Database!");
        });
    });
```

angularmodule.js

```
var app = angular.module('two_way', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('two_way_control', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.message = "Hello from controller";
    $http.get('/').success(function(data){
        console.log("http get");
        console.log(data);
        $scope.profile_pictures = data;
    });
});
```

and console.log(data) returns the whole index.html

index.html

```
<body>
    <div id="container" ng-app="two_way" ng-controller="two_way_control">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="data in profile_pictures">
            {{message}}
            <div class=".col-sm-6 .col-md-5 .col-lg-6">
                <h4>User Say's</h4><hr>
                <p>
                    This is a Demo feed. It is developed to demonstrate Two way data binding.
                </p>
                {{ data.profile_picture }}
                <img src="{{data.profile_picture}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But this code returns the mysql data in json format:

```
app.get('/load', function(req, res) {
console.log("Backend");
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM user_info;", function(err, rows){
            if(err){
                res.redirect('/error');
                console.log("Error in the database: " + err);
            } 
            res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
            console.log("Connected to the Database!");
        });
    });
```

Please help. Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fix the error in the chrome console

`"GET http://localhost:8000/%7B%7Bdatas.profile_picture%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)"`

i suggest you to use the ngSrc directive, so instead of

`<img src="{{datas.profile_picture}}">`

use

`<img ngSrc="{{datas.profile_picture}}">`

As described in the [doc](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Hope this help

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeijendekker consider to upvote my answer if you retain it useful

Answer (score 2):

In Express, you need to respond with a request. Use something such as `res.send` and send data down.

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send

> Sends the HTTP response.
>
> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an
>   Array. For example:
>
> ```
> res.send(new Buffer('whoop'));
> res.send({ some: 'json' });
> res.send('<p>some html</p>');
> res.status(404).send('Sorry, we cannot find that!');
> res.status(500).send({ error: 'something blew up' });
> ```
>
> This method performs many useful tasks for simple non-streaming responses:
>   For example, it automatically assigns the Content-Length HTTP response header field (unless previously defined) and provides automatic HEAD and HTTP cache freshness support.
>
> When the parameter is a Buffer object, the method sets the Content-Type response header field to “application/octet-stream”, unless previously defined as shown below:
>
> ```
> res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
> res.send(new Buffer('<p>some html</p>'));
> ```
>
> When the parameter is a String, the method sets the Content-Type to “text/html”:
>
> ```
> res.send('<p>some html</p>');
> ```
>
> When the parameter is an Array or Object, Express responds with the JSON representation:
>
> ```
> res.send({ user: 'tobi' });
> res.send([1,2,3]);
> ```

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.end

> Ends the response process. Inherited from Node’s `http.ServerResponse`.
>
> Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as `res.send()` and `res.json()`.
>
> ```
> res.end();
> res.status(404).end();
> ```

Comment: i already tried the res.json, res.end, res.send but those didnt work. The problem is that the $http.get is not going to the express app.get. Even console.log("Backend"); was not executed.

Comment: You can open up the network tab and see where is the $http request firing off to. I suspect your express is on a different port, and you are not including it in the URL for $http.get.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, i just need to initiate the http function

```
var app = angular.module('two_way', []);
app.controller('two_way_control', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.message = "Hello from controller";

    $scope.load = function(){
        $http.get('/LoadAll').success(function(data){
            console.log("http get");
            $scope.profile_pictures = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.load();
});
```

but i still get an error in the chrome console

`"GET http://localhost:8000/%7B%7Bdatas.profile_picture%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)"`

in `<img src="{{datas.profile_picture}}">`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<img src="{{datas.profile_picture}}">
```

to

```
<img src="{{data.profile_picture}}">
```